# Saving function for Datatable Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am using datatable JQuery plugin found on this site. http://datatables.net/

This is how I generated my table, which include three columns, checkbox column, program name and company name.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#tablePrograms').DataTable();
        });
</script>

<div id="selectedProgramIds" runat="server"></div>
         <asp:Repeater ID="RpPrograms" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="tablePrograms" class="display">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Program</th>
                                <th>Company Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="cbxProgram"/>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnProgramID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProgramID")%>' />
                            </td>
                            <td><asp:label runat="server" id="ProgramName" Text='<%#Eval("Program")%>'></asp:label></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("CompanyName")%></td>
                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My question is, now that this is a 10 pages table with pagination, what is the best way to save the data so that checkboxes selected on 10 different pages can all be saved. Currently, the DOM only shows the elements of the pages that I am on. For example, if I am on page 1, DOM doesn't display the elements on page 2-10. What is the best way to perform saving is this case? Does datatable plugin has some kind of build-in saving feature? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what about Iterate the repeater in server side

Comment: But the problem is the that items on other pages are not being shown in the DOM tree. So even if I loop over my repeater, I can only capture the items displayed on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on their website. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/form.html

A handy jQuery serialize() function can be used to string together the data.